# Usb 3 external hdd can't be seen when plugged to usb 3 port

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 16.10 (4.8.0-26-generic) on laptop Dell Inspiron 3162. It has 2 usb ports - 2.0 and 3.0.

```
Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/7p, 480M
```

And also I have WD 500 Gb usb 3.0 external hdd formatted as one NTFS partition. It works fine when I plug it to the usb 2.0 port, recognised and mounted immediately. But when I plug it to the usb 3.0 port nothing happens. This port still works with flash drives, usb mouse, but not this disk.
lsusb sees it:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
|__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
```

and:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1058:074a Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
```

But df can't see it.
dmesg:

```
[ 5441.723330] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 5441.743845] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=074a
[ 5441.743855] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 5441.743862] usb 2-1: Product: My Passport 074A
[ 5441.743869] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 5441.743874] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 575834314331323137333034
[ 5441.746816] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 5441.751215] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 5441.751406] scsi host2: runtime PM trying to activate child device host2 but parent (2-1:1.0) is not active
[ 5442.773507] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 074A 1010 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 5442.774650] scsi 2:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1010 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 5442.818861] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 5442.819781] ses 2:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[ 5442.820437] ses 2:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
[ 5473.667703] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 5473.674129] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[ 5473.851619] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 5473.872843] ses 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 0
[ 5473.872852] ses 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0xffffffea
[ 5473.872857] ses 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[ 5473.995525] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 5504.504405] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 5537.271975] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 5570.040842] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: I'd look at wd.com to see if there's a firmware update for the drive.

Comment: @heynnema the disk works and it works as usb3 with another pc

Comment: Is the drive plugged DIRECTLY into the USB3 port on the computer? If yes, after you plug in the drive, does it appear in the left pane of Nautilus file manager? Does your BIOS have any USB settings that might apply here? Have you checked for a BIOS update? Do you have access to a POWERED USB hub? If you also have Windows, go to http://support.wdc.com/product.aspx?ID=232&lang=en and download the `WD Drive Utilities` and test the drive.

Comment: There IS a BIOS update for your computer that was released in July 2016 that has USB fixes in it. Find it at http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=0WP2N

Comment: @heynnema This version (1.0.9) is already installed on my laptop

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you please answer the other questions that I had for you? I'd like to help more, if I can.

Comment: @heynnema Oh, sorry! Yes, the drive is plugged directly into the usb3 port. After I plug the drive it doesn't appear anywhere. Nautilus, Disks, `df` don't see it. but `lsusb` says the drive is plugged into usb3. As I said I have the latest BIOS 1.0.9 and it doesn't have any particular settings for usb ports. I thought it might be about power supply through usb, but the same disk works perfectly with usb2 port and usb2 devices (like mouse) work with that usb3 port.

Comment: @heynnema I don't have Windows, but before this laptop I had Acer ES1-131 with the same Ubuntu and the same disk worked perfectly with usb3 port.

Comment: The USB external disk takes more power than other USB devices, especially at initial spin up. I think that your USB3 port isn't supplying enough power. The only way to prove it is to either 1) try a **POWERED** USB hub, or 2) get a Y-cable that plugs into 2 USB ports for added power, and the third plug goes to the drive.

Comment: ps: I searched eBay for "dual usb3 cable" and found plenty of examples of the cable that I describe. Here's only one example: http://www.ebay.com/itm/31-USB-3-0-Type-A-Female-to-A-Dual-Type-A-Male-Plug-Adapter-Extension-Cable-/390648817338?hash=item5af47be6ba:g:uZcAAOSwKtVWzkdu